# get the number with the smallest value closest to the goal in the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need Obtain the nearest smallest number of an array, not the closest number

```js
var counts = [4, 9, 15, 6, 2],
  goal = 13;

var closest = counts.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
});

console.log(closest);
```

Above, the result is `15` but it should be `9` as I want the lowest number closest to the goal number.

Comment: What is your expected output, and please explain the logic/reason for the output

Comment: I need to get the number with the smallest value closest to the goal in the array.

Comment: So your expected output is `4`? It would be good if you showed an example in your question where your current code is not giving you the expected output, and then explain what your expected output is instead with a justification. You can [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: yes, but if I put 13, the result is 15 and it should be 9. I want the lowest number closest to the goal number.

Comment: That's a clearer example of the problem you're facing, I suggest you [edit] the code snippet in your question to include `13` as the `goal` and not `5`, as it's easier for future readers to see what your issue is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can filter your array so that you get an array with numbers that are smaller than your `goal` number. Once you have this array, the largest number in that array will naturally be the closest number to `goal`, which you can obtain by spreading your array into `Math.max()`:

```js
const counts = [4, 9, 15, 6, 2],
  goal = 13;

const closest = Math.max(...counts.filter(num => num < goal));

console.log(closest);
```

One thing to note, the above will struggle with large arrays (mainly due to the fact that `Math.max()` has an argument limit), a more optimised option would be to use a regular loop, for example:

```js
const counts = [4, 9, 15, 6, 2], goal = 13;
let closest = -Infinity;
for(const num of counts)
  if(num < goal && num > closest) closest = num;

console.log(closest);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var counts = [4, 9, 15, 6, 2],
  goal = 5;

const distance = counts.map((num) => Math.abs(num-goal));
const smallestDistance = Math.min(...distance);
const closestValueIndex = distance.indexOf(smallestDistance)
console.log(counts[closestValueIndex]);  // 4
```

Comment: if putting the goal = 13, the result is 15, I need the result to be 9.

Comment: (closest (or greatest) value smaller than goal…)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var counts = [4, 9, 15, 6, 2],
  goal = 13;

var closest = counts.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) && curr < goal ? curr : prev);
});

console.log(closest);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your goal correctly, you want to sort the array high to low, then loop through and return the first number less than or equal the goal.

```js
let counts = [4, 9, 15, 6, 2]
const goal = 13
let closest

counts.sort((a, b) => b - a)

for(let i=0; i< counts.length; i++) {
  if(counts[i] - goal <= 0) {
    closest = counts[i]
    break
  }
}

console.log(closest)
```